# Setting data to a class variable (from Google Places API)

Tags: ios, swift

Using the Google Places API I can search the map for a place and get info about it (for example website), using this function, called from a Search button in the navigation bar `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Search", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pickPlace))`:

```
func pickPlace() {
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.708637, longitude: -74.014839)
let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let place = place {
        // Set place to class variable selectedPlace
        self.selectedPlace = place
        // Add marker & move camera to new place
        if self.selectedPlace != nil {
            let cam = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!, zoom: 18)
            let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: cam)
            let newPlaceMarker = GMSMarker(position: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!)
            newPlaceMarker.map = mapView
            self.navigationItem.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
            print(self.selectedPlace?.website)
            newPlaceMarker.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
            self.view = mapView
        }

    } else {
        self.navigationItem.title = "No place selected"
    }
})
}
```

Inside `if let place = place` I attempt to set place to a class variable called `var selectedPlace: GMSPlace?` by using `self.selectedPlace = place`. However, when I try to print, for example `print(self.selectedPlace?.website)`, it is nil - so I think I'm not setting the variable correctly, however I'm not sure why.

How can I correctly set `place` from the `pickPlace` function to my class variable `selectedPlace` so I can use it around my app?

EDIT: To show what I'm trying to use the class variable for

I'm trying to get my custom info window to appear on a user-searched marker, and not only on my default markers. This is my customInfoWindow function - note the "default" condition is where the window should appear if the marker is user-searched, and where I'm trying to use `self.selectedPlace?` values like `name`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

    let customInfoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomInfoWindow", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! CustomInfoWindow
    let placeName = marker.title!

    switch placeName {
    case "TGI Friday's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "TGI Friday's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Thoroughly Average Chain Restaurant"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "fridays")
        self.navigationItem.title = "TGI Friday's"
    case "George's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "George's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Old School Diner"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "georges")
        self.navigationItem.title = "George's"
    case "Reserve Cut":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "Reserve Cut"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Kosher Steakhouse"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "reserveCut")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Reserve Cut"
    case "O'Hara's":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "O'Hara's"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Irish Pub"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "oharas")
        self.navigationItem.title = "O'Hara's"
    case "Bill's Bar & Burger":
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = "Bill's Bar & Burger"
        customInfoWindow.detailLabel.text = "Bar founded by Bill that also has burgers"
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "bills")
        self.navigationItem.title = "Bill's Bar & Burger"
    default:
        customInfoWindow.nameLbl.text = self.selectedPlace?.name
        customInfoWindow.placeImage.image = UIImage(named: "noImage")
        self.navigationItem.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
    }

    return customInfoWindow
}
```

Then once I get the info window to appear, I'd like to tap on it and be brought to the website - again, the default condition is where I'm trying to use the `self.selectedPlace?` values:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {

    let placeName = marker.title!

    switch placeName {
    case "George's":
        if let georgesUrl = URL(string: "http://www.georges-ny.com") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: georgesUrl))
        }
    case "TGI Friday's":
        if let fridaysUrl = URL(string: "https://www.tgifridays.com") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: fridaysUrl))
        }
    case "Reserve Cut":
        if let rcUrl = URL(string: "http://reservecut.com") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: rcUrl))
        }
    case "Bill's Bar & Burger":
        if let billsUrl = URL(string: "http://www.billsbarandburger.com") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: billsUrl))
        }
    case "O'Hara's":
        if let oharasUrl = URL(string: "http://www.oharaspubnyc.com") {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: oharasUrl))
        }
    default:
        // user-selected place
        if let site = self.selectedPlace?.website {
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: site))
        }
    }

    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
    self.view = webView


     // return to map
    var backButton = UIImage(named: "back")
    backButton = backButton?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: backButton, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleReturn))
    navigationItem.title = "Restaurant Webpage"
}
```

Comment: Is it the selectedPlace that's nil or just its website?

Comment: The website - I think my exact print statement was `print("Selected Place website is \(self.selectedPlace?.website)"` and the website was nil

Comment: Note that `self.selectedPlace?.website)` has its proper value within the `if let place = place` statement. It's just when I try to use it outside, in the rest of my class, it's suddenly nil - which defeats the purpose of trying to set it to a class variable.

Comment: When/where  do you try and print the place?  The place picker closure will execute asynchronously when the place has been picked. How does the rest of your code know that the picking is finished?

Comment: @Paulw11 @PhillipMills see my edit to see where I'm trying to use the `self.selectedPlace?` values in my class and they're coming up nil

Comment: How does this code relate to `pickPlace`? - Where do you call `pickPlace` and how do you ensure that the map view is updated *after* the place is picked?

Comment: @Paulw11 `pickPlace` is called when the user presses a Search button in the navigation bar. And I'm not sure about the second part, that's where my question comes in if you can help!

Comment: OK.  I haven't use GMSMap, but it seems that adding the map to the marker properties is what creates the relationship. Is the picker function in the same view controller as the other functions you have shown?

Comment: Yes, it's all in one view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136899/discussion-between-paulw11-and-kingtim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a new map view in your callback closure rather than adding the place to the existing map view.  This new map view is missing all of your original places and it's delegate isn't set to your view controller instance, so the delegate methods aren't called.

When you create the map view you should store it in an instance property and add the new place to that map view:

```
 if self.selectedPlace != nil {
     let cam = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!, zoom: 18)
     let newPlaceMarker = GMSMarker(position: (self.selectedPlace?.coordinate)!)
     newPlaceMarker.map = self.mapView
     self.mapView.camera = cam

     self.navigationItem.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
     print(self.selectedPlace?.website)
     newPlaceMarker.title = self.selectedPlace?.name
}
```